# Proper Fortran compiler to execute a program

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I have little knowledge of the *Fortran* language. I have come across some programs written in the 90s (see attached snapshot showing just a portion of a long script).

[image]

I'd like to know what kind of compiler is appropriate to execute such codes? I have installed [gfortran-4.2.3](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/) on my mac. I'm also not sure about the indentation in the attached code: if *C* (comment) is at column 1, does the main code start at column 9 or 7? what about the position of numbers placed in between referred by **GO TO**?

Comment: Seem to encounter error. Which errors? You can't let us guess! It's impossible to study such a long code!

Comment: The error is included

Comment: the errors are because the lines are past col 72.  You probably added a few extra spaces when you transcribed the code.

Comment: @agentp that solved some problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Fortran 90. This is Fortran 77.

That said, `gfortran` is able to compile this code. Make sure that the file extension for the file is `.f` so that `gfortran` realises it's fixed-form.

The `C` needs to be in the first column, the numbers that you reference are labels, they can be between column 1 and 5. The asterisk at line 198 is a continuation character, meaning that this should be treated as part of the previous line. It must be in column 6. Everything else needs to be between columns 7 and 72 (inclusive)

Oh, and the 3-digit numbers at the very beginning are line numbers, and **must not** be in the source code.

Edited to add: Since you have to type it all again anyway, you might as well make it free-form:

Replace the `C` in the first column with `!`, and change the way continuation lines are marked: Turn this:

```
      write (*, *) "This is some long text,  
     *  which doesn't fit into a line"
```

Into this:

```
write(*, *) "This is some long text, " // &
     "which doesn't fit into a line"
```

Everything else can stay like it is. (You can now use proper indentation, too!)

**New Edit**

So you've pasted the code that you wrote and the error messages, so I'm replying to that now.

In Fixed Form, any character past column 72 is ignored. You have a few lines with long strings, where the terminating quotation mark is in that ignored region.

Make sure that no line exceeds the 72nd row.

Comment: I'd also consider replacing the gotos with proper loops.

Comment: Please see my new edits - I'm still unsure whether it's a problem of the complier or the code. thanks!

Comment: I would not change a thing. Just figure out which editor to use to maks sure your column 6 is where the & goes. You can use .for so that if there is if any preprocessing that might creates a .f does not then over write the .for

Comment: I moved the '&' and "$" to the 6th column. can you explain what you meant by .for?

Comment: What is the name of the code? it is either something.f or something.for, and one could call it something.f90 but then you have to use -fixed on the compiler. A preprocessor will take a .for and make a .f or .fpp and compiler will take a .for or .f and many a .o or .obj . and the linker makes a .so, .exe. dll etc.